# I'm trying to pass array parameters in query to servlet. But, I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, servlets

I'm refreshing my servlet knowledge by creating a simple api after many days.
While trying to supply array parameters in query for get request, I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found error. I tried the same thing with spring framework before & was working perfectly. So, whats problem with servlet code.

Here is the request:
http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/welcome?name[]=akshay,barpute.

Below is the servlet code for your reference.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
    ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Map<String, String[]> data = request.getParameterMap();
    this.s = data.get("name")[0];
    response.getWriter().append("Hello ").append(s);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request be - http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/welcome?name=akshay&name=barpute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about that spring feature, but the correct way to do this with a servlet is to repeat the `name` parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/welcome?name=akshay&name=barpute
```